# Assign a Column with an Application Item on Data load

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to create Data loading page with data load definition. For Whatever Data that i upload, I have an "CURRENTTEAM" application item which i want to set as default (fk column) for all new rows from bulk upload. This column does not exist in the excel sheet that is being uploaded. It is only in the sql table.

Ive tried making a dynamic action and running it when the user clicks "Load Data" . This does not work for large amounts of data for some reason.
[Load Data Button being clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjMo.png)

PL/SQL code being run in the dynamic action :
UPDATE RAWCUSTREQS
SET TEAM = :CURRENTTEAM
WHERE TEAM IS NULL;

:CURRENTTEAM is the application item that contains the unique team ID that is used to separate the Data. Therefore depending on who is logged in, i would be able to filter out the data based on the “TEAM” column. It only affects the rows where the “TEAM” column is empty, the idea being that it was just uploaded by the user. This brings up issues when multiple users are uploading at the the same time. So this isn't a solution aswell.

Comment: Figured it out. Shared Components --> Data Load Definitions --> Click your Data loader --> Edit Data Profile --> Add in the Column u want to update with the App ID --> Set the Column type as SQL Expression and set the expression as: v('NAME_OF_YOUR_APPITEM')

Comment: You should put that as an answer. Self-answers are allowed (and encouraged) - leaving answers in comments on the question is discouraged.